# Win32 Console applicaton hangs at start without hitting breakpoint

Tags: c++

In my C++ Win32 Console application in debug mode (of Visual Studio 2013) when I run it, the console windows appears but it just hangs at the start and doesn't hit any break points.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int y = 0;
    B::CTest *c = new B::CTest();
    //int t = c->CTest::test(10);

    //std::cout << t;
    return 0;
}
```

When I comment out the line

```
B::CTest *c = new B::CTest();
```

it works and hits the first break point at the beginning.
Any ideas why this is?

EDIT:  Constructor definition

CPP

```
B::CTest::CTest()
{
    //return;
}
```

HEADER

```
namespace B{
#define TEST
    class TEST CTest{
    public:
        CTest(void);
        int test(int i);

    };

}
```

Comment: Post the definition of `B::CTest`. It seems like the constructor causes the problem.

Comment: @BetaCarotin added additional info. as requested

Comment: Break in with the debugger and see what code is stuck.

Comment: @RaymondChen how do I do that? I'm running in visual studio.  Is there an option to do this?  I'm already in debug mode.

Comment: Just press pause, it should stop where you are and also give you a call stack trace.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖI don't understand what is wrong with my question, I edited it to provide more information as requested. You might want to reword your comment for politeness sake.